# WordPress: Add custom add_filter for custom functions

Tags: plugins, php, filters, hooks, email

I am coping with the scenario where I need to filter content of my custom function. My function is used for sending emails but I need to filter it just like wp_mail hook do.

Here is my function:

```
function koku_crm_send_sendgrid($sendgrid_api_key, $to, $subject, $text, $html) {

  $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($sendgrid_api_key);
  $mail = new KCSendGrid\Mail();
  $from = new KCSendGrid\Email(get_bloginfo( 'name' ), get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ));
  $mail->setFrom($from);
  $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

  $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/plain", $text);
  $mail->addContent($content);

  $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/html", $html);
  $mail->addContent($content);

  $personalization = new KCSendGrid\Personalization();
  $to = new KCSendGrid\Email(null, $to);
  $personalization->addTo($to);
  $mail->addPersonalization($personalization);

  $sendgrid->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

}
```

I want to filter that "$to" variable before sending the email. Something similar to the [wp_mail filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail).

I have search a lot, please help me in this regards. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply_filters` function:

```
function koku_crm_send_sendgrid($sendgrid_api_key, $to, $subject, $text, $html) {
  $to = apply_filters( 'koku_crm_send_to', $to );

  $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($sendgrid_api_key);
  $mail = new KCSendGrid\Mail();
  $from = new KCSendGrid\Email(get_bloginfo( 'name' ), get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ));
  $mail->setFrom($from);
  $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

  $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/plain", $text);
  $mail->addContent($content);

  $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/html", $html);
  $mail->addContent($content);

  $personalization = new KCSendGrid\Personalization();
  $to = new KCSendGrid\Email(null, $to);
  $personalization->addTo($to);
  $mail->addPersonalization($personalization);

  $sendgrid->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

}
```

The first argument of `apply_filters()` is the name of the filter. It's what you'll use when calling `add_filter()`. The second argument is the value to be filtered.

Now you can filter `$to` like so:

```
function wpse_276933_send_to( $to ) {
  $to = 'new@example.com';

  return $to;
}
add_filter( 'koku_crm_send_to', 'wpse_276933_send_to' );
```

You can pass more values into the filter callback function by adding arguments to `apply_filters()`. These won't do anything on their own, but it means that they will be available when adding the filter. So if your filter was:

`$to = apply_filters( 'koku_crm_send_to', $to, $subject, $text );`

You could access `$subject` and `$text` in your filter function by including the arguments in the callback function and setting the fourth argument of `add_filter()` to `3`, so that the function knows to accept 3 arguments:

```
function wpse_276933_send_to( $to, $subject, $text ) {
  if ( $subject === 'Subject One' ) {
    $to = 'new@example.com';
  }

  return $to;
}
add_filter( 'koku_crm_send_to', 'wpse_276933_send_to', 10, 3 );
```

Read more in the Plugin Handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/